# In Gradle: set Scala encoding to UTF-8

Tags: scala, gradle

If compiling Java in Gradle, you can set the encoding via

```
compileJava.options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
```

I can't manage to get this to work with Scala; I've tried all of these:

```
compileJava.options.encoding = 'UTF-8'

compileScala.options.encoding = 'UTF-8'

compileScala {
    scalaCompileOptions.encoding = 'utf-8'
}

compileScala {
    scalaCompileOptions.additionalParameters = ["-encoding UTF-8"]
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

**Edit: closing as it was my test methodology that was at fault.** I originally had `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS -Dfile.encoding=UTF8` set; I was trying to replace it by setting the encoding in the Gradle file.

To test I was trying to print out a Unicode character and it was not printing correctly after removing the envvar and trying the options above. The reason was that `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS -Dfile.encoding=UTF8` affects not only the input file encoding but also the encoding of `System.out`. Overriding that with

```
System.setOut(new PrintStream(System.out, true, "UTF-8"))
```

fixes thing. For reference,

```
compileJava.options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
compileScala {
    scalaCompileOptions.encoding = 'UTF-8'
}
```

is enough.

Comment: did you add dependency and config for scala compiler plugin

Comment: I'm guessing, but does `["-encoding" "UTF-8"]`, or whatever the right Groovy syntax is for having two strings here instead of one, work? it's two parameters, not one.